# Get AWS SSM Parameters Tags without Get Parameter

Tags: python-3.x, boto3, aws-ssm, aws-parameter-store

I am trying to list of all Parameters along with all their tags, I am trying to do so without listing the value of the parameters.

My initial approach was to do a [describe_parameters](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.describe_parameters) and then loop through the Key Names and then perform [list_tags](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.list_tags_for_resource), while doing so I found out that the ARNs are needed to perform list_tags which are not returned in the describe parameters.

Is there a way to get the parameters along with their tags without actually getting the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the resource groups tagging api *IF THEY ARE ALREADY TAGGED*.  Here's a basic example below without pagination.

```
import boto3

profile = "your_profile_name"
region = "us-east-1"
session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name=profile, region_name=region)
client = session.client('resourcegroupstaggingapi')

response = client.get_resources(
    ResourceTypeFilters=[
        'ssm',
    ],
)

print(response)
```

If you're wanting to discover untagged parameters, this won't work.  Better would be to setup config rules to highlight these issues without you having to manage searching for them.

Comment: Would the untagged instances not be visible with this approach?

Comment: No unfortunately.  I tested and confirmed prior to posting the answer.  The tagging api only reports on tagged items.